# Menu & popupmenu: размер текста и иконка

Tags: android, popupmenu, android-menu

Вопрос: как в менюшке изменить размер текста (например, очень длинный текст, нужно вместить). Сделать мельче или в 2-3 строки? 
И как добавить рядом с названием иконку?
Min 13, target 19.

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали, о чем речь идет.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu